# Linux kernel module: Socket buffer (sk_buff->len) non-deterministic behaviour

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have a kernel module that reads packets from netfilter hook and use `sk_buff` to access the data.

What I am observing that when packets are coming at slow rate, `sk_buff->len` behaves normally but when packets arrive at higher rate (1Gbps etc) then `sk_buff->len` for few packets starts to increase (always a multiple of 8).

The data I am replaying has fragmented packets as well. Is it that fragmented packets gets appended in same `sk_buff` causing an increase in `sk_buff->len` ? If yes, how `sk_buff` is aware of the stack and at what point ?

Can someone explain that why it happens and how to get around with that. Any reference to some documentation will be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is GRO (Generic Receive Offload). It's an optimization on the receive side just as TSO or GSO. It appends packets with same tcp and ip headers in one big skb buffer to make kernel processing easier.